# Finding the extrema of a function

Tags: functions

I want to find extrema of functions but my code does not work for some functions, such as `Abs[x^2-5x+6]`.

Here is the problem:

[image]

```
  Clear[f, der1]
Manipulate[Grid
  [{{Column
     [{Row[{Framed[Style["Extrema of function", Bold, Red, 25],
          Background -> LightBlue, RoundingRadius -> 20]}]}]},        
   {Column
     [{
      InputField[Dynamic[f], Background -> LightYellow],    
      der1 = Simplify[D[f, x]],   (*the first derivative*)
      dom = Simplify[FunctionDomain[f, x, Reals]],     (*domain*)
      Reduce[der1 == y, y, Reals],   
      zeroder = Solve[der1 == 0, x ],     (*first derivative = 0*)
      discontin = 
       Solve[Denominator[Together[f]] == 0, 
        Reals], (*points of discontinuity*)
      noder = 
       Solve[Denominator[Together[der1]] == 0, 
        Reals],  (*points where the first derivative does not exist*)


      extr = 
       Union[Sort[
         Join[{axxfr}, {axxto}, {zeroder}, {noder}, {discontin}]]],  \
(*list of extrema*)
      Maximize[{f, axxfr <= x <= axxto}, x],        (*axxfr = 
      axis x from....,     axxto = axis x to....*)
      Minimize[{f, axxfr <= x <= axxto}, x], 
      Plot[f, {x, axxfr, axxto}, PlotRange -> {axyfr, axyto}, 
       Background -> LightGreen]    (*axyfr = axis y from....,    
      axyto =  axis y to....*)
      }]}}],
 {axxfr, -5}, {axxto, 5}, {axyfr, -2}, {axyto, 2}]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example: The whole `Manipulate`-related stuff does not seem to be the core of the problem. Also, this being an international site, it might be seen as courtesy to translate or simplify the variable names.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It does indeed bring an interesting spin to the question when variables are in Czech(?).

Comment: Also, it would be welcome that the problem would be reduced in code size, at least a little. Is it `Minimize` or `Maximize` that's the problem? I see no trouble with your expression there. The logic of code is pretty hard to follow especially due to the variable names which mean nothing to most of us. In order to help you, it is really necessary to pinpoint the problem; unfortunately it's next to impossible without a little bit of clarification.

Comment: Try it with `RealAbs[x^2-5x+6]`

Comment: Supplement to my previous comment:
`RealAbs`is continuous and differentiable everywhere except at the origin and `Abs`is not. `RealAbs`is introduced in version 11.1

Comment: If `RealAbs` is not available, you can also use `Sqrt[(x^2 - 5 x + 6)^2]`

Comment: Thanks Bob Hanlon but the code has to work for all functions and my teacher told me: It has to work for Abs[xx-5x+6].

Answer (score 4):

First, here's a plot of the function:

```
Plot[Abs[x^2 - 5 x + 6], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

```
Chop /@ FindMinimum[Abs[x^2 - 5 x + 6], {x, -5, 5}]
```

(*

{0, {x -> 2.}}

*)

or

```
Minimize[Abs[x^2 - 5 x + 6], x]
```

(*

{0, {x -> 2}}

*)

To get the second minimum, start above the $x$ value of the first minimum:

```
Chop /@ FindMinimum[Abs[x^2 - 5 x + 6], {x, 2.5, 9}]
```

(*

{0, {x -> 3.}}

*)

You know you can only have two such extrema in such a quadratic (with ABS) function.

A more general way to deal with continuous functions is to take the derivative, set it to zero, find all solutions, then check the values of the function at those points and select all that have the (same) minimum value.

Comment: It could work but the code has to work for all functions, not just for this one.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I noticed that there is even no plot of the function (at the screenhot). I don't understand why the code doesn't work for the plot of this one function. My teacher told that it should be easy to do it right.

Comment: Why does not the plot work in my code above?